# Drop one letter of a given string that has two consicutive letters

Tags: string, dart

I am trying to workout a simple algorithm in `Dart/Flutter` that checks a given string and if it has two consecutive letters it removes one of them.

> input: hello, foor, deed, foot

> output: helo, for, del, fot

This is what I have done so far :

```
dropDoubleLetters(String str) {
  List<String> strArray = new List();
  strArray = str.split('');
  String finalizedStr = "";
  for (var counter = 0; counter >= strArray.length; counter++) {
    finalizedStr += strArray[counter];
    if (strArray[counter] == strArray[counter + 1]) {
      strArray.removeAt(counter + 1);
      finalizedStr += strArray[counter];
    }
  }
  print('word is :' + finalizedStr);
}
```

The problem is the output of this method is always null, it always returns in this format:

> flutter: word is:

How to workout this algorithm and what am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `counter >= strArray.length` is wrong since the indices are in range(0, strArray.length - 1). Next, the `finalizedStr` variable is useless since you are modifying the original `strArray`. So the `strArray` itself is the answer.

```
dropDoubleLetters(String str) {
  List<String> strArray = new List();
  strArray = str.split('');
  for (var counter = 0; counter < strArray.length - 1; counter++) {
    if (strArray[counter] == strArray[counter + 1]) {
      strArray.removeAt(counter + 1);
    }
  }
  print('word is :' + strArray.join(''));
}
```

Another approach is to check every character with the previous one:

```
dropDoubleLetters(String str) {
  List<String> strArray = new List();
  strArray = str.split('');
  String finalizedStr = strArray[0];
  for (var counter = 1; counter < strArray.length; counter++) {
    if (strArray[counter] != strArray[counter - 1]) {
      finalizedStr += strArray[counter];
    }
  }
  print('word is :' + finalizedStr);
}
```

*Note: In the first approach every character is compared to the next one(`strArray[counter + 1]`), so the counter should be at most `strArray.length - 2`.*

Answer (score 2):

I know nobody asked for this so don't mark this the answer. But if somebody else are thinking "This can be solved by using a regular expression" then here is the answer to that thought:

```
void main() {
  final wordList = ['hello', 'foor', 'deed', 'foot'];
  print(wordList.map(dropDoubleLettersRegExp).toList()); // [helo, for, ded, fot]
}

String dropDoubleLettersRegExp(String str) =>
    str.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\w)\1+'), (match) => match.group(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over >= strArray.length, starting from 0, which means that your loop eventually will do strArray[strArray.length] which throws an exception because you are going out of bound, remember that your last element is at ( strArray.length - 1 ), try to change that ">=" in ">" and you should be fine.